# Can a AC generator be powered by D.C.?

Tags: power-quality, identification, frequency-synthesis

I have a very specific need. 
I need to avoid a VFD due to its square waves - my research requires exact sinwave frequencies of electrical current.

With that said 
I have a Tesla turbine which powers a AC Generator. The tesla turbine is powered via heavy water - For reasons I can't go into the power is collected, transformed a number of times and then fed back into the water apparatus to 'push' down on the water which then goes back into the tesla turbine.

I need a way to generate AC from the turbine, convert it into D.C.for storage, the the D.C. Needs to be able to be fed back into a reliable AC sinewave for reuse. Probably by a AC gen...

What I was thinking is to have the AC generator which is being driven by the turbine ->feed to a battery stack, have that power stored as D.C.- Then have the D.C. Which is stored to Power a AC generator ...
The catch - I need the AC frequency to be modular - as in I need to be able to change the final AC frequency at will...

A VFD produces square waves - so I thought the second AC gen would be ideal.

Any thoughts, problems I'm going to have and solutions?

Comment: For the DC to AC part, if you're happy with a standard frequency, just use a pure sinewave inverter. No need for an AC generator there.

Comment: I think you're stuck on this DC-generator-with-AC-exciatiton scheme when you could just use a stepup transformer...

Comment: What frequency and power do you need?  You could poossibly use a sine-wave oscillator or signal generator, and an audio power amplifier.

Comment: The direct frequencies I need are 10-12hz, 70-90hz, 130, 260-340hz . Power is variable. To put simply my amperes need to be under 16 milla amps. The voltage however needs to be between 15kv to 100kv . So 240 watts to 10kw

Comment: This has gone off the deep end, moving from engineering to pseudo-science -- a topic we don't entertain here. When you start using phrases like "reasons I can't go into" and "What most people don't know" it raises all kinds of flags that we're straying off the path of established scientific principles.

Comment: This sounds highly suspiciously like you are trying to make an "overunity" system LOL

Comment: "Tesla turbine is powered via heavy water.". Really?  What in the heck are you up to?

Comment: No I'm working with a table top particle accelerator using high voltages and resonant frequencies accelerating diamagnetic gas in a closed system. Again thanks for your comments but I'm working with high velocity fluids that will exhibit very high electromagnetic fields which are harmful. Not everyone who is working on theoretical physics are trying to do pseudo science thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drive the second AC generator with a variable speed dc drive they are manufactured for propulsion systems these days. This will give you variable frequency.

Comment: Oh perfect. I'll have a look. I can control the rotation this way of the AC gen and this the frequency obviously. Perfect. Do you know any affordable ones? And possible AC generators that connect?

Comment: given your voltages you are going to need a transformer on the output after the generator.

Answer (score 0):

Square wave VFDs have not been made now for almost 20 years. They are all sine coded PWM, the output of which can be made to be nearly sinusoidal by adding the right kind of filters. It would be basically the same kind of output you would get from a double conversion UPS. If you need a truly variable frequency output, this is really the only way to go. But if you only need to switch between 50 or 60Hz output, then a solar inverter would likely be less expensive.

Comment: What most people don't know is that a sine wave is a 2D Representation of a 3D action. Pure sine waves are actually electrons/electrons rotating in a circle clockwise or anti clockwise. From the side it looks like it's a wave but in fact it's rotating but while it rotates it's propagating in a specific direction. The issue with VFDs is that they are cutting the rotation and because they only display a 2D DIsplay you can't get an pure sine wave - the requirement is for a 100% pure Sine wave unfortunately. Frequency range needed is 10-350hz , 250 watts to 10kw. (To start )

Comment: Protons/electrons

Comment: If they ever get a 3D VFD then I'd be all for it but I'm working with resonances and there can't be any fluctuation

Comment: This is sounding more and more like magic.

Comment: @JoshuaH I'm pretty sure you're mixing some concepts from different fields here. Unless you're trying to achieve cyclotron resonance, electrons don't rotate in circles in electronic circuits. Just like the laws of quantum physics prevents us from being able to tell one electron from another, the output of a perfect band pass filter will look the same irrespective of what drives it. In short: Add enough filtering and you can get pure sinewaves from anything (Variable Frequency motor Drives or otherwise).

Comment: When I'm done my test I'll show you that they do. Regardless I got my answer to my issue so cheers everyone :)